# Wireless performance, normal results

Tags: performance, wifi

Here is the setup:
An IBM server machine connected to a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND (latest firmware). It is connected with a wired gigabit connection.

An lenovo laptop with a centrino wireless-n 2230 and a Atheros AR8151 (wired).

When I connect to the router using a cable, I get gigabit speeds when transferring (95-99 megabytes per second).

When I connect to the router using wireless, when I go to the wireless properties, I see a connection at 300 megabits/s. The problem is that when I transfer the same file, I am only getting 3-6 megabytes per second (24-48 megabits per second).

I have a ea2700 and an ea2500, both do worst then the TL-WR1043ND. For testing purposes, there was nothing else connected to these routers.

Is this expected wireless speed or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not surprised by those numbers, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. The wifi software on your computer can't know for sure the maximum throughput of your connection, because things like congestion, collisions, interference, etc all factor in, so it guesses. It seems that your adapter's software is exceptionally poor at guessing. In instances where performance matters, wireless cannot be relied upon. It's an excellent convenience, but precisely because of what you're seeing, it can't be the only medium.

Also, 300Mbps is likely a MIMO 802.11n connection. Not all MIMO devices are created equally. You get excellent performance from the $900 Cisco 3600-series APs, but probably not as great from devices in the price range that you're testing with.